# How to import data from Firebase only once at login

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code is kind of buggy lately and I wonder if the methods I am using to retrieve data from `Firebase` are the correct methods to use. In short, I am retrieving data from `firebase` and than storing it inside an `SQLite database`.

This is my code:

```
FirebaseStore.rootRef.childByAppendingPath("users/"+FirebaseStore.rootRef.authData.uid+"/forums").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock:{
    snapshot in
    guard let firebaseData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {return}
    guard let uids = firebaseData.allKeys as? [String] else {return}
    importContext.performBlock{
        for uid in uids{
            guard let forum = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Forum", inManagedObjectContext: importContext) as? Forum else {return}
            FirebaseStore.rootRef.childByAppendingPath("forums/"+uid+"/posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
                snapshot in
                            // Saving the chat's messages
                            guard let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {return}
                            importContext.performBlock{
                    guard let posts = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Post", inManagedObjectContext: importContext) as? Post else {return}
                    do{
                                            try importContext.save()
                                        }catch let error{
                        // Error
                                        }
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
}
```

I am not sure if I have to call this `observeSingleEventOfType`.

Comment: Which version of Firebase are you using? What are the bugs? Also give your JSON tree, and what exactly do want to achieve with this function.

Comment: I think I am using v 2.5.1 of Firebase and the problem is that when I import the data, not everything gets imported, but not at each launch.